# select to sum the values of one column to other

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I have a table TABLE_A with one column.

```
select VALUE from TABLE_A;

VALUE   
---------
1         
2
3
4
5
```

I need a second column which will give me sum of all the values of first colum.

Expected:

```
VALUE     SUM
--------- ---------
1         15
2         15  
3         15
4         15
5         15
```

I need to do this without a sub-select query.(select in place of a column)

Comment: "*I need to do this without a sub-select query*" That is exactly my answer intends to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be easily done using **SUM() OVER()** analytic function.

```
SELECT VALUE, 
       SUM(VALUE) OVER(ORDER BY NULL) as "SUM" 
FROM TABLE_A;
```

**Working demo:**

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  -- end of sample_data mocking as real table
  3  SELECT 1 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 2 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 3 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 4 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 5 VALUE FROM dual
  8  )
  9  SELECT VALUE,
 10         SUM(VALUE) OVER() as "SUM"
 11  FROM sample_data;

     VALUE        SUM
---------- ----------
         1         15
         2         15
         3         15
         4         15
         5         15
```

Comment: Seems like I need to learn those fancy Oracle features some day.

Comment: @jarlh It is standard SQL, just remove ORDER BY clause. It is allowed to remove ORDER BY clause in SUM analytic, unlike few analytic functions where ORDER BY is mandatory.

Comment: I'm surprised.  It actually does work with `order by NULL`.  To me, that should do a cumulative sum, but there must be some special rule about this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It will work. But my bad as it is meaningless here to use `ORDER BY NULL` since it is allowed for SUM analytic function unlike it is mandatory for other analytic functions, in such cases to avoid `ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification` error while we do not need ordering we use `ORDER BY NULL`. So I have removed it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a sub-select that counts:

```
select value, (select sum(value) from TABLE_A)
from TABLE_A
```

Or `JOIN`:

```
select t1.value, t2.sum_value
from TABLE_A t1
    CROSS JOIN (select sum(value) as sum_value from TABLE_A) t2
```

Does Oracle support `CROSS JOIN` syntax?

Comment: can i do this with out a sub-select? because this is a concept that i am trying to implement for a major sql. So a sub-select will be slow

Comment: Yes Oracle supports cross join

Comment: Compare the execution plans and chose the faster one!

Comment: Sure Thanks for the suggesstion

Comment: Not efficient solution to scan the table twice. Analytic function could do it in one step.

Answer (score 0):

Just use analytic functions.  The correct expression is:

```
select VALUE, sum(VALUE) over () as "sum"
from TABLE_A;
```

This is a standard part of SQL and usually more efficient than other methods of doing the same calculation.